# using underscore to total array elements with coffee script

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, underscore.js

i have this list which contains an arrays:

```
invoicedItems = [
  { sku: 'EP01-MGY1'
      quantity: 10
      unit_price: 473
      vat: 0
      price: 4730 },
  { sku: 'EP01-MGY2'
    quantity: 80
    unit_price: 426
    vat: 0
    price: 34080 },
  { sku: 'EP01-MGY3'
    quantity: 1
    unit_price: 612
    vat: 0
    price: 612 },
]
```

what is the correct way to add the totals for `price` and `vat`, so that i get:

```
{ goodsTotal: XXX, goodsVAT: YYY }
```

i tried this:

```
if invoicedItems
  console.log invoicedItems
  result.invoicedGoodsTotals = 
    goodsTotal: _.reduce( invoicedItems.items, ((s,it) -> s + it.price), 0 )
    goodsVAT: _.reduce( invoicedItems.items, ((s,it) -> s + it.vat), 0 )
  console.log result.invoicedGoodsTotals
```

but this did not work.

only returned

{ goodsTotal: 0, goodsVAT: 0 }

Any advise much appreciated.

Comment: Change `invoicedItems.items` to just `invoicedItems` and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to call `_.reduce` twice for this. The memo for `reduce` can be anything; in particular, it can be an object:

```
summer = (memo, it) ->
    memo.goodsTotal += it.price
    memo.goodsVAT   += it.vat
    memo
totals = _(invoicedItems).reduce(
    summer,
    { goodsTotal: 0, goodsVAT: 0 }
)
```